# Any decent Eclipse plugin for monitoring Jenkins?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jenkins

I have found an [old plugin](http://code.google.com/p/hudson-eclipse/) for Eclipse from 2009 to monitor a Hudson server but it has two major drawbacks:

1. No support for multiple Hudson/Jenkins servers
2. Clicking on a Job in the view results in a window showing a 404 exception

Does anyone know a newer (maintained) Eclipse plugin for Jenkins?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a Mylyn connector for Hudson, which also works for Jenkins (Update site is http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest/)

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_Extensions list reference to only 1 commercial plug-in http://tasktop.com/connectors/hudson-jenkins.php

Comment: That wiki page is obviously outdated. The connector was commercial, but since Mylyn 3.5 it is freely available with Mylyn Builds.

Comment: After using another stand-alone Hudson plug-in for Eclipse...I gotta say that this Mylyn one is really great.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse *Juno* includes the Mylyn Builds view. It shows the last built time and a summary of your build plans. You can directly see test results and jump to the corresponding code. Build failures are marked red just as in the Problems view.

```
Menu -> Windows -> Show View -> Mylyn Builds
```

If you don't have it, install it:

```
Menu -> Help -> Install New Software... -> http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/juno
   choose
   Mylyn Integrations -> Mylyn Builds Connector: Hudson/Jenkins
   Mylyn SDKs and Frameworks -> Mylyn Builds
```

They are also available for Eclipse *Indigo*.

Normally the Builds view automatically connects with your Hudson/Jenkins server, just wait a few seconds. If not, add it manually. Just don't add it multiple times, since there is no easy removal mechanism (except removing the plugin's xmi file in your eclipse workspace).

The server preferences allow for adding individual build plans. Click refresh first.

Don't forget to activate "Refresh Automatically" in the view menu.