# Mylyn jenkins connector gives always Service Unavailable

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, mylyn

I have installed the hudson/jenkins mylyn connector for eclipse (as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543067/863180)

I have configured my jenkins, but i always this error: Server validation failed: Unexpected error: Unexpected response from server while logging in: Service Unavailable

This is the complete error:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_13
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -showlocation -product com.jboss.jbds.product.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showlocation -product com.jboss.jbds.product.product

Error
Wed Jul 31 08:39:16 CEST 2013
Server validation failed: Unexpected error: Unexpected response from server while logging in: Service Unavailable

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unexpected error: Unexpected response from server while logging in: Service Unavailable
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.HudsonCorePlugin.toCoreException(HudsonCorePlugin.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.HudsonServerBehaviour.validate(HudsonServerBehaviour.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.internal.core.BuildServer.validate(BuildServer.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui.spi.BuildServerPart$Validator.run(BuildServerPart.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui.RepositoryLocationPart$2.run(RepositoryLocationPart.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.HudsonException: Unexpected response from server while logging in: Service Unavailable
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.HudsonOperation.run(HudsonOperation.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.RestfulHudsonClient.validate(RestfulHudsonClient.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.HudsonServerBehaviour.validate(HudsonServerBehaviour.java:902)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response from server while logging in: Service Unavailable
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.HudsonOperation.authenticate(HudsonOperation.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.http.core.CommonHttpOperation.executeOnce(CommonHttpOperation.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.http.core.CommonHttpOperation.execute(CommonHttpOperation.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.RestfulHudsonClient$8.execute(RestfulHudsonClient.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.RestfulHudsonClient$8.execute(RestfulHudsonClient.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.hudson.core.client.HudsonOperation.run(HudsonOperation.java:167)
    ... 6 more
```

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It works after changing my java version to jdk 6. (But I have no clue why)