# Run Jenkins plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm able to maven-build a Jenkins plugin project on Eclipse. Is there a way to directly run the plugin in Eclipse? So the Jenkins user interface can show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108700/any-decent-eclipse-plugin-for-monitoring-jenkins

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky not a duplicate, OP is asking how to run from Eclipse a Jenkins plugin he's developing/modifying. Referenced questions asks about an new version of an Eclipse plugin which allows Jenkins remote monitoring

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correct you want to hit debug in Eclipse and get Jenkins with your own plugin installed.

Add the information to your settings.xml file in your .m2 folder according to
[Jenkins Plugin Tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-SettingUpEnvironment)

In Eclipse, add a new maven build configuration (under run -> run configuration...) with the base directory set to your project (where your pom-file is) and hpi:run as goal.
Choosing to run this configuration in Eclipse will start a new Jenkins instance within a Jetty server (you won't have your old jobs or data there, but jobs you create will be saved between runs). Hitting debug instead will start Jenkins in debug mode.

Set a breakpoint in your code (Eclipse might warn you about not being able to set the breakpoint due to some line number compile options, but it will work anyway) and open your Jenkins administration page at localhost:8080/jenkins.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such an option.The [maven hpi:run](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-hpi-plugin/run-mojo.html) seems to be the closest option to what you desire, as described in the [jenkins plugin tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial). There is [an alternate eclipse setup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Eclipse+alternative+build+setup#Eclipsealternativebuildsetup-Configuringjenkinsforfaststartup) but it seems to be even less "compatible" with your request.